# Mod_rewrite and complex redirection technique recomendations

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

im trying to solve this issue. I have a web site with this simplified struture:

```
mysite.com/index.php
mysite.com/faq.php
mysite.com/url.php
mysite.com/users/some_content_here
```

If the user call the *index* page or the *faq* page they have to arrive to that pages. BUT if the user writes something like mysite.com/**xgsfd** (or any other string different than *index* or *faq*) they have to call the url.php wich recive the *xgsfd* string via GET and redirects the user to a particular page.

The url.php script is already done, but i have no idea how to solve the other part, im was thinking using a .htaccess file in the root directory but as you can see it will trigger a infinite loop of rederictions.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use rewrite conditions to serve files, folders and symlinks if they actually exist, but otherwise rewrite to the url.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ url.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That way requests to faq.php or index.php will be served, while a request to mysite.com/xgsfd will end up rewritten to url.php?url=/xgsfd .